# MVC Model binding of complex objects Html.dropdownlistfor not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, modelbinders

When i use simle model and pass in view example a copy of the model-everything worked well.

in controller

```
 AdvertisingStructure mc = context.AdvertisingStructures.Single(a => a.Id_show == id);
        if (mc == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(mc);
```

in view

```
 @model  Sciencecom.Models.AdvertisingStructure
 @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Owner.Id, new SelectList(owners, "id", "Name"))
```

the value of the list selected

But i inserted this model in complex objects and pass in view example a new copy-html.dropdownlist stopped working(the value of the list not selected )

new model

```
   public class CompositeModelForEdit
{
    public AdvertisingStructure Structure;

    public IEnumerable<Side> Sides;

    public IEnumerable<Surface> Surfaces;

}
```

in controller

```
  AdvertisingStructure mc = context.AdvertisingStructures.Single(a => a.Id_show == id);
        List<Surface> surfaces=new List<Surface>();
        foreach (var sides in mc.Sides)
        {
            foreach (var surface in sides.Surfaces)
            {
                surfaces.Add(surface);
            }
        }
        return View(new CompositeModelForEdit() { Sides = mc.Sides, Structure = mc,Surfaces = surfaces});
```

in view

```
@model  CompositeModelForEdit
     @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Structure.Owner.Id, new SelectList(owners, "id", "Name"))
```

have any ideas(field input display value)?

Comment: Does not look to be anything wrong with the code you have shown. The first example is a complex model anyway (`AdvertisingStructures.Owner.ID`). Have you checked that the the `Owner.ID` property is being correctly assigned and has a value that matches one of the options?

Answer (score 0):

Your models are different, yet in the SelectList you use the same properties - Id, Name. I'm guessing that your **AdvertisingStructure** class contains those properties, but the **CompositeModelForEdit** does not.

EDIT:
First of all, do not use such a complicated viewmodel, use something simpler, for example:

```
public class OwnerViewModelForEdit
{
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public string  Name { get; set; }

    //....
}
```

Then in your GET action, you can define your list of items that you want to appear in the dropdown:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ownersList =
            owners.Select(o => new SelectListItem() {Value = o.Id.ToString(), Text = o.Name});
ViewBag.Owners = ownersList;

return View(new OwnerViewModelForEdit(.........))
```

finally, in the view define your dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.OwnerId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Owners)
```

And then in your POST action bind the viewmodel data to your respective Owner model and you are done.

There are many answers on Stackoverflow, regarding mvc dropdowns. If you search a bit, you will find an even better suggestions.

Comment: Can you offer any solution?Or how to use 2 model for binding in one view without complex model?

Comment: I edited the answer, so that you can see it with code coloring